# Lubuntu 20.04: context menu "Compress" not working after replacing ark with file-roller

Tags: lubuntu, context-menu, file-roller, ark

I recently installed Lubuntu 20.04 and being dissatisfied with the archive manager Ark I decided to replace it with file-roller.
Everything is fine except the "Compress" action in the context menu (when you right-click one or more files) does not work (nothing at all happens).

Any idea how to fix this?
And more generally, where are these context menu actions ("Compress", "Open in Terminal", ...) defined?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look under the file manager's Preferences > Advanced > Archiver Integration?

Comment: Also, please limit your question to one specific issue.

Comment: @DKBose The archiver integration fixed it, many thanks! (Weird that ark is not removed from the archiver intergration option list once it is purged from the system)
If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it and mark the question as solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lubuntu 20.04 allows users to specify certain archiver tools to be used from the right-click menu in pcmanfm-qt.

The user can make this choice from pcmanfm-qt's *Preferences > Advanced > Archiver Integration*.

[image: Setting the archiver]

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!